# Configuring UI package theme from main app

Tags: reactjs, state

I am currently working on a project where we use an external component library (external package) that needs to follow our main app's theme rules. Basically, I have to implement a method that when called in the main app passes its parameters to the component library.

What would be the best way to approach this? (I'm a react beginner so probably the solution is really obvious) I read that I can achieve this using redux but was wondering whether there's a better (or simpler) way to do this?

Comment: could you provide any code examples of your problem? and perhaps the name of the external library (if it is open source)? Otherwise, reddit or a discord channel might be a better place to get help.

Comment: @KostasKarakepelis, What external component library do you use?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers, the ui library we use is built by us, prettymuch what I need to do is pass a color object array from the main app to it.